# Como cadastrar uma nova Person quando cria uma nova Customer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

po estou com uma questão já a um tempo quebrando a cabeça, seguinte, tenho uma model Person, que é a generica para pessoa e a model Customer, que pertence a Person, assim:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_one :customer
  has_one :address, as: :addressable
  has_one :phone, as: :phoneable


  accepts_nested_attributes_for :address, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: :all_blank

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :phone, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: :all_blank

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :customer, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: :all_blank

end
```

e a Customer:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person
  has_one :address, as: :addressable
  has_one :phone, as: :phoneable

  validates :person_id, presence: true

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :phone, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: :all_blank

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :address, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: :all_blank
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :person, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: :all_blank

end
```

No Customer_controller eu setei os strong params para que aceite os atributos de Person ao ser criado, dessa forma:

```
 def customer_params
   params.require(:customer).permit(
    :customer_code, :name, :cpf, :rg, :birthdate,
    addresses_attributes: [:id, :street, :number, :neighborhood, :state, :nation],
    person_attributes: [:id, :name, :cpf, :rg, :birthdate],
    phones_attributes: [:id, :phone1, :phone2])
  end
```

No formulario eu inseri o simple_fields_for :person do |ff| 
Porém não está cadastrando o person, somente o customer.

Se puderem dar uma ajuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como dpedoneze comentou verifica se você está instanciando o objecto build_person antes de iniciar fields_for

eu iniciaria dessa maneira na view:

```rails
f.object.build_person if f.object.person.blank?
f.simple_fields_for :person do |ff|
```

Outra coisa que está me deixando um pouco intrigado é essa relação de Person com Customer.

Uma pessoa tem um consumidor? Qual é a responsabilidade de cada entidade?

Só um detalhe, você está usando que versão do Rails? Senão me engano, na versão anteriores a 3.x o acceptd_nested não funcionava com belongs_to.

---

Respondendo a sua resposta no comentário:

Vou te dar uma cenário para você analisar ai.

Não seria melhor setar uma field no Person tendo person_type e mesclar os colunas do customer com person.

Pq assim você teria algo assim

```rails
Person.new(person_type:'Costumer')
```

ou no futuro

```rails
Person.new(person_type: 'Company')
Person.new(person_type: 'Agent')
```

ou também usar STI

O model de identificação se chama User?

Comment: Olá Breno, obrigado pela resposta, so para responder suas perguntas, uma pessoa tem um consumidor por que um consumidor é uma pessoa, e a versão do Rails é a 4.2.6

Answer (score 1):

Fala Jean, tudo bem?

De cara, podemos ver que temos duplicações de relações, visto que temos:

```
has_one :address, as: :addressable
has_one :phone, as: :phoneable
```

em `Person` e também em `Customer`.

Os campos de `Person` aparecem no formulário? Talvez seja necessário um `customer.build_person`.

Outra dica é validar relações sem o `_id`, apenas `validates :person`, normalmente validamos as associações sem o `_id` e utilizamos o `_id` para validações de unicidade.

Normalmente o rails verifica a relação ao criar mas você pode deixar isso explicito com a utilização do `inverse_of` nas relações. [Mais informações aqui](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#options-for-belongs-to-inverse-of).